# about mobilefirst platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

guys i am very new to developing mobile app . my company gave a task to read mobilefirst platform and work on mobilefirst studio to build an simple hybrid hello world application.i have successfully created and also previewed in android version using emulator.i found the apk and installed in mobile and i ran it showed hello world after opening the app. My doubt is i have put the mobile on flight mode still the app runs showing the hello world result then WHAT IS THE USE OF MOBILEFIRST SERVER ????how it shows even though there is no data internet in mobile ??? help pls i am very new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a new application, a "Hello World" application. This application only *displays the text "Hello World"*.
An application that only displays text and does not attempt to connect to any external server to retrieve data will simply Just Work because *you did not add any code that requires Internet connectivity*.

What you need to do is to *read the Getting Started tutorials*, from start-to-end, with patience, and you will **learn** that you can add features such as Adapters which provide the ability to retrieve data from various backends, such as SQL or HTTP.

To use Adapters, the application will requier an Internet connection. The app will send a request to the MobileFirst Server which then calls the adapter to retrieve the data and send it back the application.

APP <---> SERVER <-> ADAPTER <---> BACKEND

There are additional features which also require an Internet connection, such as push notifications, security, and so on...

**READ THIS**

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/

From the top to the bottom.

Comment: Thank u idan u r helping me a lot